# Shift input parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

Given the following stored procedure, I'd like to be able to shift my input parameters so if the first parameter isn't a valid date, the 2 other parameters that are dates are shifted as the input. I also want to have the current day be used if there are no input parameters to my stored procedure. What is the best way to do it? I'm using SQL Server 2008 r2.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_qIMO_TEST_2] 
     @i_InstrumentID VARCHAR(15) = NULL,
     @i_DateLow      DATETIME = '20090101',  
     @i_DateHigh     DATETIME = '20291231'   
AS
IF @i_DateLow IS NULL SET @i_DateLow = CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))
IF @i_DateHigh IS NULL SET @i_DateHigh = CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))
    SELECT * FROM
     (
            SELECT 
                 out_interface_id,
                 msg_id, 
                 CAST(xml_msg as XML).value(
                    '(//InstrumentID)[1]','nvarchar(15)') AS InstrumentID,
                 msg_type,
                 xml_msg,
                 CAST(xml_msg AS XML) as [Quick_XML], 
                 date_received,
                 status,
                 last_modified,
                 environment,
                 transaction_closed_date
            FROM MyTable
            WHERE msg_type IN ('ABC','DEF') 
            AND date_received >= @i_DateLow
            AND date_received < DATEADD(DAY,1,@i_DateHigh)  -- Need to add 1 to the DateHigh for 
                                                                                                        -- date range criteria to work properly (>= and <)
     ) x
     WHERE (x.InstrumentID = @i_InstrumentID OR x.InstrumentID = NULL)
     ORDER BY date_received DESC
RETURN
GO
```

**Updated for more clarity**

Basically, I want it to check if the first argument is a valid date, probably using `IsDate()`and if it isn't a valid date, then I know it is an InstrumentID. If it is an InstrumentID, I want to check if the next argument is there. If it is there, check if there is a 3rd argument. That would indicate that all 3 arguments are there so I know it is a valid InstrumentID with start and end dates. If there is only a valid first argument, I want it to use the current date for the 2nd and 3rd arguments. I know it's convoluted but that's what I've been asked to do. There is no front end app, so I have to do it in a T-SQL stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ISDATE function to check if the first parameter is a valid date. If it is not use it as a InstrumentId. For second requirement, Make the date parameter defaulted to NULL and in the SP check ISNULL(2ndpara) , ISNULL(3rdPara) That should work.

Comment: Updated my solution. Let me know if it is not clear to you.